# symfony 4 app on heroku with remote database

Tags: heroku, symfony4, remote-access, proxies

I really need some help here hehe
Ok i got a symfony 4 application that is working perfectly in local environement.

I installed the app on heroku, but i want to access my Mysql database on my web hosting.

To be able to do that i had to install the Fixie app on heroku to have two ip adress and be able to whitelist those address for the remote access of my database.

The app is running good, but if i go to any links that have a call to do at the database i got a timeout.

I think the problem is in my index.php file, when installing Fixie you have to add code to the trust proxy

Heres what i have right now in my index.php file

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require dirname(__DIR__).'/config/bootstrap.php';

if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}

$trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false;
$trustedProxies = $trustedProxies ? explode(',', $trustedProxies) : [];
if($_SERVER['APP_ENV'] == 'prod') $trustedProxies[] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if($trustedProxies) {
    Request::setTrustedProxies($trustedProxies, Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB);
}

if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);
}

$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Thats the log message i get when i try to access a page that have a call to the database

```
2019-11-28T22:13:12.218311+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-28 22:12:42] request.INFO: Matched route "publicResultat". {"route":"publicResultat","route_parameters":{"_route":"publicResultat","_controller":"App\\Controller\\PublicController::index"},"request_uri":"https://jugement.herokuapp.com/public","method":"GET"} []
2019-11-28T22:13:12.218435+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-28 22:12:42] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
2019-11-28T22:13:12.220033+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-11-28 22:13:12] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out" at /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\ConnectionException(code: 0): An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out at /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:93, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out at /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:31, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out at /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27)"} []
```

When you install fixie in heroku you have to add something this is the example they give for php but i don't understand how to do that in my symfony app

```
PHP cURL is the easiest way to get your PHP application working correctly with Fixie. Here’s how:

<?php
  function proxyRequest() {
    $fixieUrl = getenv("FIXIE_URL");
    $parsedFixieUrl = parse_url($fixieUrl);

    $proxy = $parsedFixieUrl['host'].":".$parsedFixieUrl['port'];
    $proxyAuth = $parsedFixieUrl['user'].":".$parsedFixieUrl['pass'];

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyAuth);
    curl_close($ch);
  }

  $response = proxyRequest();
  print_r($response);
?>
```

Hope that i am clear on my problem

any help would be very useful

I also found strange that i have no header present when the call is done

```
Request URL: https://jugement.herokuapp.com/public
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Thats all i have in the header

Comment: Using the heroku console, were you able to log into the mysql running on your server?

Comment: Im using heroku console how can i test connection for my db?

Comment: I'm not really sure how you'd do that but generally a PDOException has something to do with connecting to the database. It cannot connect to the db, it kept trying until it reached timeout. Check your connection string again and the Fixie docs. They might have something there that could help.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the fixie doc show what to add but not sure how to put this in my symfony app, i will continue to try things :)